# Use custom image path for different stores in email template in Magento

Tags: magento

I have created Transactional email template for sending emails for different stores.I have used an extension which allows admin to upload logo for his store.That logo is uploaded in folder media/uploaddir/stores/ for example media/uploaddir/stores/1/abc.gif for storeid 1.Now i want to use the store id and image name dynamically for different stores so that I can send store logo using same template for all stores.How can I do this?